# How to center markpoint in multiple series in echarts

Tags: javascript, echarts

I actually want to add a symbol to display the growth rate between two sets of x-axis data. So, I came up with the idea of using markpoint to handle this.

[Example Playground #1](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&version=5.2.2&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoW7YCIzGAG0hEwC5k0MLsAnCAc1oFMqSsIwGBbTAGnIvUwBDAB4QAzgAVgEaO2alU_JVjABPEAxaYAxlWBixmPvwC-xk70q0aAExaLlmPAwBmYLQGYApD2OUatAAW7qSYACw-lo4ARsBgOFyh3r7KWNowYIIyADKC0Qx4LGBUAK4M5lECzozQdgp-GNgMwmAAymrO9g1KOvjA8lgAxABCYaOjRqlmFBbGmMIAgqKGpADa3WSplGoaWtqC7LT9qilbAiLiufmF9Wc9MnIAboI3sACMGzOVW5g2B4IsdZ3fiYABMAAZQR5wQBWU7AgTg-EIsGQ6EANmRwMwbyxd1RUPBAHY8WcwaSfhDCQAOCmpTAeOmOKnQgCcTJ6YQ5IJZbyR32xcIF-N5uOFZMx4spaLeoMmdwAuhtphgFd9MKoluJARsHGSdppQs88GV5UoVeg1XMxEwIAwVrAgco9T9oIIOIasGLPo0DVpooJmFLKH9MjqEY0IeCAHTg_k-pTQEp4PDB5lx2PxiPoJMptM9KOZ7kUXOphM8jNx4sYUv5isxqt1kvJsvZrCFxvl5t5ruRytZ7O13sCDtI8tW7F4PIFLptzDQfocF6ztuNMSBYAAdyKpQYTccIH0bCg0C0OCIw9gFq2sxRS6oAGspA8VxHMGJVBxYnhWhAAF6ek6q6wGE4L7kooGXhO2bvp-34APIuC4NohI6l4UGB6EYOCUHgVgoYAmsWHoC6wECOk_R1GhZE_AONFKHy1LEfw0H0VgxqmqEAC0oLRh4yR4fSH5fvgWggAcgTEAA9FJACybweNG1JvG83AqYEimsm81J4Fx6JKTCMLcES2RhLGoKqSpAAS1Kxh46LaOCXEwlxbzRjC6LUlxtkuWZrKsh4rlvAAwkS0YBUSalqbx1L8dwYRqYpymWW8ABa1ZklO1yvmxjSHmIx4wP6cQJGa9HXm2t5kaRZG9JR4a5ZQ3qNRQfJhMxFCsfRmAcZ6mB6eFbyRB1a5waJoTiWAkkyfJSUqWpbwaYNOkDdShnGaZ5kpTZdkOU5LluR5Xk-VxfkBUFoXhR4kWWTFcUJQpSnzSp6WCY4WUzrcLUCPlhWnqEsTxMAXAjegFXZlVwE1cBdVUFRQEteSb1nHyOGNV1NE9S8nFYDGYSssNjWwSJryYJN01yY9yXGUtWnUtkfJKUSCVgWZkKqUSO3gvZjncAd7medwJ1nR4C2XRFak3XdotvA9c0c69oNYB9rzQ91v2QEVAMlcDZU0eDEaQ6uatzhRcMNd9DIZQifIeErGO1b1WhsxE1tCWNpPk9JlPyzTmnaQzMbUsz3Cs1txlczzYH80dQvuad4UBWLYUS28UtKXFsuJU9Ctu-906q0rlAayexVAyDjUGwiRttibMFm_DReNFyyNbHyML263lBO9xMaggTec9MJ35iRJ3uzTnC209pun6WtRkmWzFkLZHe3Oa5AvHfHIsXSn11RbKGei3Lk8vYPIIqzlRMl1rWCA6VStV8CNfZnXb4NxbiNCk36B8uindKyxiaPqvF-KE1ysTEeE0x4zSpvNIk096aM2DizeK4dOa2W5ntPmG9Y7C0TjLEKe8brp1ijLE-1MiSKyJpfL6lsb7_TvjrCuuUn53BfhGN-KIP5EW-gISUP93hpwAUTHuXoYTRnRAPLuo0SajymuPOBHNEGByZqgpeHNV68xjoLfB_lCHi33mnaKR81IUPgdQiBtDNh8LJkeTWjDMD311o_ZibClBKmrsqYU3RjBKhMEAA)

However, this method fails when I want to use multiple sets of series data.

[Example Playground #2: Multiple series](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoW7YCIzGAG0hEwC5k0MLsAnCAc1oFMqSsIwGBbTAGnIvUwBDAB4QAzgAVgEaO2alU_JVjABPEAxaYAxlWBixmPvwC-xk70q0aAExaLlmPAwBmYLQGYApD2OUatAAW7qSYACw-lo4ARsBgOFyh3r7KWNowYIIyADKC0Qx4LGBUAK4M5lECzozQdgp-GNgMwmAAymrO9g1KOvjA8lgAxABCYaOjRqlmFBbGmMIAgqKGpADa3WSplGoaWtqC7LT9qilbAiLiufmF9Wc9MnIAboI3sACMGzOVW5g2B4IsdZ3fiYABMAAZQR5wQBWU7AgTg-EIsGQ6EANmRwMwbyxd1RUPBAHY8WcwaSfhDCQAOCmpTAeOmOKnQgCcTJ6YQ5IJZbyR32xcIF-N5uOFZMx4spaLeoMmdwAuhtphgFd9MKoluJARsHGSdppQs88GV5UoVeg1XMxEwIAwVrAgco9T9oIIOIasGLPo0DVpooJmFLKH9MjqEY0IeCAHTg_k-pTQEp4PDB5lx2PxiPoJMptM9KOZ7kUXOphM8jNx4sYUv5isxqt1kvJsvZrCFxvl5t5ruRytZ7O13sCDtI8tW7F4PIFLptzDQfocF6ztuNMSBYAAdyKpQYTccIH0bCg0C0OCIw9gFq216-uvL8_dnvJdew6mfAaDD9DALWl9RDYDhGQ5zqO1Y5i2-4jv24GwCB2YAUWUFwZB_5gch8ERohnZtphKLoZeeHYmB46vlO1wrlhC5UEurwunO65bjuZTIZQh5iMeMBnqAZoIreyj8egsypPRjhuh6njcm-uyhJ-Uk_uGCEQkhhGoXOfIqbhakIW8mmDtpWEeHpwEGfhgGwUR-IaTh-k9qB5kYaZ2KsuZpEPuRM63Ah1G0ZRq6YIx26kMULGXmxR6QFxoTnrxwKCaYypSqJPTic-XKvn6smBvJ_yKVhyk2SZdlKQ5qnFVhumgnKjnlSilXVWVrY6dGVUWU5VmlVptXYtZQEIpZZIFWOwITviHl0f-PnLl5q5YIFzF7mFjTsZxp7RTxl7xTMiX3tiS5UAA1lIDx-diYiqBwsR4K0EAAF6ek6s1hOCrEYM9l6jVh52XfgADyLguDaISOkt6AvaDsDgh9yG_Llf6zegyX-ek_R1CDCM_H1GMUHy1IQxQn3Y5gxqmqEAC0oLRh4ySvT031XVoIAHIExAAPSswAsm8RnUm8bzcHzgRGaybzUngZPotG1IwjC3BEtkYSxqC_N8wAEtSsYeOi2jgmTMJk7pMLotSZMa_riusqyHgG28ADCRLRlbRICwLlPUtT3BhALPN8wLbwAFqwfS42ndjAgrZFa1YLE8TAFw-MYFtdzCQjSNzijVBo49YeNN6Of8HyYQJ5atMgiTz4S47byRMXc0XQzoRM2ALPs1zPsq28QtV2LlfS7L8uK5CHfq5r2u6_rhvG6b0bm47Vs2_bjseM7Ktux7Xvc1Lvt84HpeUCHM351gEcnv6cQJLFCNJ2cKezWnCEZ1nteUA1R8YHyUP54TGPEy8pNYDGMIrIa75wCvXfAjNmZs05pvXm_MiRdxFtSbIGlqREi9i9Qeys5Yj3BFrHW3AJ4z2NtwM2ZMLZWz9ovJ2AsV5rw8ALDe7c5a71rk4acE037hwiqfWS5846X1mtfG8pd75YUfnlI-DIg53D5B4Wu38Ea_xNGlWMEQZF03Aa8TATcW4wOYQg4WosUExjQRgz2St4G4PwS9IhRtqSkJnuQueDC-bUOXrQ12UsPZvCYVveBrDQEH02FwnRPCorR34fHfOwipiiLYRI-GoT0rP3frCBRe9Gjly0GTGMoJgEaJBPTCBjcoGt1gdvTuRie6Sz7nLBWli_bWLHnrA2xCTZkIodbNxDsaGr28QwvxcC_aBJzuwiih9QEnwiZgGOF9a6xIEvE0BiT0ahKFKk9AfJ0QZLYdk0IlNqYgLGcU7RujoFt38XLRBxjUHoO4JgxpRJmkELsSQzpLiqG9I8W8OhAzGHeyuUSUZYdxmeRCW_MJHFI5n1jtEnOizzTLLGas7OoDJSbPeL83ZoD9lehhNGdEBTMkCFOZA5uFyKnwJucgu55isFWI1ngsehC2n2McbPS2ri7bfJXn892rihm-2BYU_eHDQ6gumVHWZUTBGrkRQlNsSo4oZXfP6bKr4FJrEUXTDcQVYAuBeDaV8bBODtFUJ0SZ-IpqcKUaAQQ2g2AnFIJ_bMwjb4_DwDIBg5rLUQpRDaiVKJ7WOrUCwV1EZ3VkQYDUGwqtgCPCYNkGQB0WCGrwMah8ghoAQCXDC4Ku5lTGCVCYIAA)

I'm trying to figure out what step I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This solution will solve the problem

> What seems to be working quite fine is to use a second value axis to position the bars manually (which would also allow for the markPoints to be [positioned via the value](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggjDAvDA2lsBXAGwIBoYAmABgoDoqBdU3Qk8q2ih7fI0ym-xtxZ92nJj1b8Og5rzYCusyaJkSR9OgG4AUKEixEyMhmzjh86YrUWxQuVNtL1ls_ZVXzD1Z_evlGnT1oeCQEAGYTHDtWX2iULw9SFFilMJTrdPNMpIS_SmyYAE4HLV1wYMMEABZIvNzo_IU_ZLIyRwkWtu8k6lb2lniCwaaGkp1tADMQACcYAAoCAFNYAEswOEWADxgQCewKYhRiMmIw4iriAFZiADZiAHY6AEoYAG9tGBDkFCw1jc26FgOCY5n8tjAAFQwAAcLwA1DAUDpPpUyL91ltAcDMKCMdsobCYAiyMivuF0f8sXQQWD8TD4TAwqTKlUKZigdScbTIfSiTAqjoAL5lfQwTYAWQQ20w9x50L50Ool3GIAADlAVuATO9PlAQCACBrVQAuN4fT4wKDTFYAcxti2mpoA5CsoIsALZO4jmz5SlYQAAKIDWbsdZotFqgAE9VYtncBpiAIBAnT6YMLPoLvZ8bda4KadRalhMoM6wgBSL1p602gAWpZgTqqlezFoARiAoHr3WWW2m9Mg1gAZBBtxYEU1WvCLc1Z81Le3rAtpt2bKAAZWjS2XEc-oAIM2dAGIAEJVM9n1MRjPp1ubACCm39pqwacLEejsedADcEARp1Wu4wBAtYgAA7qaEx_hAiythG7pSqaEpSmmc4Ru-kYxnGjbAEgiw2jMUaAbuqpJq6mpgM6HZdiAnpwRalQvmmEZOpQZBhBQlzEUBrEUOxFA3Nxu68fx9xCSxbEcdC4kWiJHGFDJnxyfEimNpJKAoKpylkFeu50KhrYMOaUaPs-2BvsxlpYT-f4Aah5pGZ8MHWosEBMehllgAg7rYU6mn0bq1mNm2CDTDJjFkkclkEKO447kBMBgDMCETuGCVOaBEGWtM04BSRZEauAzp6qqulATe14GRZQFeT5zo6Xln6-SFYV5RFqJ5TFY6pRhEZJdMKXxelIHgZOOWwZZEakRA5FFY2JVlbuFUWstaEWr1iXeb5YQyU1VGheFoSmpUZzRbFPWTYlyV_kNCUjVlU4TelnzTbNlHzWqi2VeVVUeTVW3OlUu1BU6LWHcgx2hBcZ3dbdfXXRdz3AZlY25ZdL0FRRxWfZdy2ZnlLUAOIICaMAALQ0IUVO_etlkIdMADWQYhnDFoQFG7odgQ64rAAXthWBVAc_LSJd7OcwaADyEwTDBDZAqQovpRFr5IxtQGgDM-bYHciIUNCjlIzAv7_r5ZNkNQYQVqpEbi1zxro8JqpILWxoAPRu-KKBpNCGmHCgtZpIUKDQgQZM3NQ0KXNc9xDlUtBkEcGkABKKhQYQ3MAFBk5cZPJJcNzQmTiq5_HVNhHnKAAML3NQhRhPchyHBb0JW-chw-37GkAFo20W52s-lr2Fe9oOdt2X0JXjS15X9Rua9M2tYCgFx61UhtIyb07OuHdcoH2RvARz9uOyxztQK7Hte53ScB0HIdhxHUcx3HCe36ntAZ1nOd50qhfF0qMmZd66VxrnXBuTcUAtzbhcb2kcu4oF7rPXcXU4ppUPsPLGwVx60Unj9JGa10rq13AvJerQchKyNlvXyNAqiFAPkbO2BoHaHyUufS-ns4G-yOPcQOe9oRDkGNCe4FwDjxz4jwj-6dM4HFzvnQuxAS5ALrvXf2YD66NxQJo6BZwV4d3gTwpBp8YCoMRqwzBc0x40U9MY6e15kGfGIRGUhL4OI5DCBvZ61DAa0GbH3Jyx9mHGLYS7d2nCb4PD4cHARQiRHEDEW_B4Uiv6yN_gXaEijAHAN0dXWuGjDjaMjm3PRXC_b3CMYfUxg8EoWNHtRCetjHaEISk4i0LjsBhAyXrS4nj0reMbBTXo9D_FHwlhOYJjZ2FhOvgY_2USH672fg8V-Ej_bJJkT_eRRclHZNAXkiBScdHt1KbfCpRsqnoKNrUqiOCbGHzsStBxlz0rtMFrreINxekJX6axS21snkBLGSw1hToplXxOZE--MSaDCNEecRJ9x1lZyuGkhROyVE5PUQcwprddGwIieUkZFzWlTUxpY-puDGkEKeSSmArzLirw0o8AFxtbK-RQJcagNxhksqYeM1hkzQngoJfM6Fkc4kJNWYitOKSUVbMyaXDFaj9maJxcU_FszCUsuJRM652DrF4KWk0y6-lyqNRBmDNqR1sBfPupBaCT1dyug9JuKM25nkWn6oND1EY1QIGAK6KMpoKC40ss0z4BA1iLFde64hXqbo-otH6gN0Zg2hrNdFfCix1jJxAN-B0Q41gM3tQQGCeUEBgBWAhEeqMZzfRgPpQUmggA) axis if applicable). Just make sure to use `barGap: -0.999` or something similar for the bars to look decent.
>
> [Example](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=MYewdgzgLgBAJgQyggjDAvDA2lsBXAGwIBoYAmABgoDoqBdU3Qk8q2ih7fI0ym-xtxZ92nJj1b8Og5rzYCusyaJkSR9OgG4AUKEixEyMhmzjh86YrUWxQuVNtL1ls_ZVXzD1Z_evlGnT1oeCQEAGYTHDtWX2iULw9SFFilMJTrdPNMpIS_SmyYAE4HLV1wYMMEABZIvNzo_IU_ZLIyRwkWtu8k6lb2lniCwaaGkp1tADMQACcYAAoCAFNYAEswOEWADxgQCewKYhRiMmIw4iriAFZiADZiAHY6AEoYAG9tGBDkFCw1jc26FgOCY5n8tjAAFQwAAcLwA1DAUDpPpUyL91ltAcDMKCMdsobCYAiyMivuF0f8sXQQWD8TD4TAwqTKlUKZigdScbTIfSiTAqjoAL5lfQwTYAWQQ20w9x50L5VWol3GIAADlAVuATO9PlAQCACBrVQAuN4fT4wKDTFYAcxti2mpoA5CsoIsALZO4jmz5SlYQAAKIDWbsdZotFqgAE9VYtncBpiAIBAnT6YMLPoLvZ8bda4KadRalhMoM6wgBSL1p602gAWpZgTqqlezFoARiAoHr3WWW2m9Mg1gAZBBtxYEU1WvCLc1Z81Le3rAtpt2bKAAZWjS2XEc-oAIM2dAGIAEJVM9n1MRjPp1ubACCm39pqwacLEejsedADcEARp1Wu4wBAtYgAA7qaEx_hAiythG7pSqaEpSmmc4Ru-kYxnGjbAEgiw2jMUaAbuqpJq6mpgM6HZdiAnpwRafoQCOY4TuGQEwCGDq_qxKBppm9EoqEL58RaTqUGQYQUJcxFAU6FAybuYkUBJFA3ApEZOig6mieJkn3NpnxiQZja6RQ0LGU6YQWaZhQWVU1nKWE8QWdJAk6Y5KBaW5hlqd5JkeWQV67nQqGtgw5pRo-z7YG-ImfthTrcQBqHmuFnwwdaiwQMJ6EiWACDuglXlxVhVEINM2mVKalRHCJBCjuOO7sWAMwIaxGFASB4GTtM05-Z8pEQOR4DOnqqpBUBN7XqFsVAflhXOoFbnxWVFVuVVZInHVDXtSJnwtdMbVNexwGgRBlq9bBe0WoNw2UY2Y0TbuU0Wi9aEWh1MDzQlVnLaVjZtuVlVCWSZzbSxx27gdR1sSdXXnVOV0nQNZEaiND1qk902TTNuVzQVCX2X9X4A0D60gyybn1RDsNQ61f6Q51Z09X110o0NaP3U6j3XS9_EiYD0wAOIICaMAALQ0IU0u4x9IkPk-EAAJJ4qatVAQh0wANZBiGjMWhAUbuh2BDrisABe2FYFUBz8tI12G8bBoAPITBMMENkCpD2ydG2vsjtMnaAMz5tgcleoiZlpQHMBJQl4tkNQYQVsZEaOybxps4pqpILWxoAPT5-KKBpNCnmHCgtZpIUKDQgQ4s3NQ0KXNc9xDoqylHJ5AAS0K0GENzABQ4uXOLySXDc0Li33o-KtLYRjygADC9zUIUYT3IchyJ9CyfnIcpfl55ABaqdFjt-snbdnNUZ23ZY-xfPPf1gfscH0yh1gmkR_EVTRwHcdnQNzXigPsMdgJGwzlnDSOcoB50LsXQ-XdK7V1rvXRuzdW7t1oGQZBvd-6D2HqPcek9p5KnFnPdei8V5rw3lvFAO894XBLk3I-KBT4v0-NTRqr8r6oworfGinpoHpizu9E6n0gLv0_kZHIPsY6AMbDQKohQwEx3TgaTO4DDKwPgUXFhZcjj3CriA6EQ5BjQnuBcA4HdcEPHwRQAeQ8rhjyVJPYgM8KFr3XhXGh69N4oACYws4KBmFIIeBwkR3DdraJgNfARAM760QfjjAO4j2KSN3NIl8lkf6OP_sjRRTZaDNjPulSBmiRE6NzgXfR4TjGoLMRYqxxAbE4KMQ4pxBxiFuOhB48hlCQnL1Xv4w4QSm571CQfVhRjIngOiZfdi8T0ZOmovfERT9rwv0yRGbJYciaR0uAUk6RTJa9FUWUiBTsJxVMbLo2piCZkVxMTXOuwDMEPGwZ3CunTCEj1cRPKenjBnUJGXQruwT94GLYXMmOCzeFLP4SstZySNliO2SIvZX9XKRxuMc9iRTE7JzUQHDRNzYlOnuQg6FRiXm13MTQSx1jzjtPsX3RxhCXEkL6cC7xQy_HgvGbvEJYSnn3FhQHeFOySJIq5ii4R4DNmvQxeArFTpfKIkCfioCRSUCXGoDcC5nCrlQIpVSupYq6VNMZS0tp3z7i_OcT0wF_TZ58t8WCgJQrJmisMREy5UrbnLLlUkhVMclWZmuiFSaxMEqC2BsgF8-L4aQWgkjXcroPSbijNuBF0MGYIs-GqBAwBXRRlNBQXmIl0lcLWIsbNubMn5picjYtpbowVqrTGuq-FFjrG7iAb8DohxrC1qmggME3IIDACsBCN8LrThSp8EKgpNBAA)
>
> MatthiasMert's comment: [apache/echarts #19485](https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/19485#issuecomment-1882616914) - GitHub